# How to simulate a Modbus traffic in GNS3?

Tags: tcp, modbus

I'm working to a project which is about creating a simple 2 router and 2 virtual pc configuration on GNS3. I created it (look for the link of the screenshot below) but now i have to simulate a modbus traffic in this net. Is this possible? How can i do that?

here you have the screenshot of what i've done until now

https://mega.nz/#!GvhD2CbJ!cPIrwTXdE-L_cyqdo2Ac8XkUhEaiUMfeJ0BdHXNsOao

Comment: Good question. I never used GNS3 but I think you can mix virtual and real devices so even if you don't have a virtual Modbus device in GNS' library you can always use tools like libmodbus or pymodbus and add them to your virtual network. Or use real Modbus hardware if you have it too... I used this approach together with Wireshark and it is a great way to understand the Modbus traffic on your network.

Comment: i also thought to something like that, but actually it is not that simple. I should install VMWare, create a VM and then installing modbuspol onto it. i looked for something like that on the web but  i found absolutely nothing :(

Comment: Why do you need the VM? You have many Modbus tools for all OS.

Comment: because i don't find yet a tool for GNS3 or for Dynamips. The only tools i've found are for windows/linux so i guess i have to start with a VM